# disable checkbox when dropdown list is change

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a problem with jquery here. what i need is, when a dropdown change then an ajax will check record in the database whatever its has recoreded or not. if yes, i want to disable the checkbox. so user cannot check it again. the problem now is, the checkbox is not working.. i already try .prop and attr.. dont know where is the problem. hope someone will help me..

here the code

```
        function checkRekod(tahun, bulan, empid) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: "../../Payroll/CheckPayslip?tahun=" + tahun + "&bulan=" + bulan + "&empid="+ empid,
            });
        }

        $("#dpMonth, #dpTahun").change(function () {
            var bulan = $("#dpMonth").val();
            var tahun = $("#dpTahun").val();

            $('input:checkbox[id="naikgaji"]').each(function () {
                empid = $(this).val();

                var rekod = checkRekod(tahun, bulan, empid);
                rekod.success(function (data) {
                    if (data == 1) {
                        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: do you have more than 1 check box with id=naikgaji? I tried this and it works  $('input:checkbox[id="naikgaji"]').prop('disabled',true), https://jsfiddle.net/e7pcu5jn/... if yours doesn't work, then something is wrong with your logic.  Make sure it gets there.

Comment: @kasperite: no error in my console..
chungtinhlakho: yeah.. that why i use the .each()

Answer (score 0):

you can try with some like that

```
 $('input:checkbox[id="naikgaji"]').each(function () {
    var chk   = $(this);
    var empid = $(this).val();
    var rekod = checkRekod(tahun, bulan, empid);

    rekod.success(function (data) {
        if (data == 1) 
           $(chk).attr("disabled", true);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $("#dpMonth, #dpTahun").change(function () {
        var bulan = $("#dpMonth").val();
        var tahun = $("#dpTahun").val();

        $('input:checkbox[id="naikgaji"]').each(function () {
            empid = $(this).val();
            // stored id in the local variable for disabling the element by this id.
            var elementId = this.id; 
            var rekod = checkRekod(tahun, bulan, empid);
            rekod.success(function (data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                   $(elementId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have your tried like this?          `$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: Please share your html source of input  checkbox  element.

Comment: <input type='checkbox' id='naikgaji' name='naikgaji' value="437de450-6654-4d18-9aa5-c2299374e7ed" class="checkboxes">

Comment: I have modified the answer, please try

Comment: Have you find time to verify it?

Comment: If it works! Please mark as answered. So that it will be helpful for others as well.